# Adding and removing elements from an array in a while loop in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have to add two new_element's to a structure array(active_nodes) in a while loop in Matlab. The addition of elements depends on the true value of an if statement. I am using the following way but this has made my code really very slow as I can not do preallocation of 'active_nodes'. Can any body suggest me some efficient way to do this job. As the exact lenght of this array is not known in advance and first deleting an element and then adding two new one in every pass of the while loop is causing the program to slow down greatly.By the way I have only one element in the array 'active_nodes' at the start of the while loop.

```
while isempty(active_nodes)==0

    current_node = active_nodes(1);
    active_nodes(1) = [];
        if fval < some_statement
        [new_element(1), new_element(2)] = calculating_new_element(current_node)
        active_nodes = [new_element, active_nodes]
end
```

Comment: Your situation precludes anything from speeding up computation.  You don't know how many nodes are you're going to have and usually vectorizing or speeding up code requires a lot more to be known *a priori*.  There's nothing here that I can see that will help you with regards to speedups.

Comment: I don't see where you're ever generating more than one new element to replace the element you've deleted. It appears that all you're doing is emptying the structure array, so there must be something missing from your example. It also seems that it would be faster to add/delete elements at the end of the array rather than at the beginning.

Comment: beaker I have made the necessary change in the example now please have a look at it. The problem is that the code becomes really very slow as this array active_nodes has to change its size two times almost in every pass of the while loop (once at the beginning when an element is deleted and once after 'if' statement when two elements are added after the true value.)

Comment: I've posted a possible solution, but I wanted to add a tip for you. If you tag someone using the `@` like @beaker, they'll get notified that you've responded to them. It's not necessary if you're responding to their question or answer, just on comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can eliminate the deletion of elements by adding new elements to the end of the list (in effect, reversing the list and reading it backwards) and using a pointer to hold the largest valid index. This also eliminates creation of *some* of the elements.

You can eliminate the creation of elements altogether if you have some idea of the maximum number of elements you'll have in the list at any one time by preallocating the array.

```
active_nodes = zeros(1, MAX_ELEMENTS);    %// if possible
active_nodes(1) = first_element;
p = 1;        %// current highest valid index

while p > 0

    current_node = active_nodes(p);    %// "pop" top element from stack
    p = p - 1;                         %// and point to next element
    if fval < some_statement
        [new_element(2), new_element(1)] = calculating_new_element(current_node)
        %// order of new_element values reversed, because list is reversed
        active_nodes(p+1:p+1) = new_element;
        p = p + 2        %// 2 new elements in list
    end
end
```